# "Cannot update a component XXX while rendering a different component XXX"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I declare a state variable in my App component which will pass it down to multiple components. One of this components, uses the setter function inside a setInterval which starts with the handleClick function. I know that normally you'd use useEffect, but where exactly should i put it? I tried in different places but none worked. (I had to rewrite this as an example, my code would be too long, hopefully there are no mistakes)

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Component from "./Component.js";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return <Component state={state} setState={setState}></Component>;
};

export default App
```

Component.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const Component = ({ state, setState }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  const id = useRef();
  const handleClick = () => {
    const work = () => {
      setNumber((n) => {
        if (n>2) {setState((s) => s + 1)};
        return n + 1;
      })
    };

    setActive(!active);

    if (!active) {
      id.current = setInterval(work, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(id.current);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{state}</button>
      <p>{number}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Component
```

Comment: I created a sandbox with your code but I can't reproduce the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-moon-dd2o15?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you were right, I edited the code and verified that it gives the error now in the sandbox. Also helped me realize that the error is likely caused by calling setState from inside setNumber

Comment: Yes, it's probably what is causing the issue. Why don't you move `setState` outside of `setNumber`?

Comment: this code is just an example. In the real code I have if statements and setState is executed when number has certain values. I added an if statement to make it more clear.

Comment: Can't you use `useRef` for `number` instead of `useState`?

Comment: No because both number and state are values that are displayed on the screen so i need to rerender

Comment: You can rerender manually https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-thunder-8g7pkh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you are passing the state multiple times down, it's best you use [Context](https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context) and this is how you can do it will `useEffect` https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bose-yek7x1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm going to need some time to try this out, but I'm fairly confident that this solves my problem. You can go ahead and answer if you want, i'll upvote both of you. I like user16967562 answer a bit more since i find it more intuitive and it doesn't use a reducer.